# Get real image width and height

Tags: javascript

When I use `image.width` it returns the image's width which appears on the screen, and I use `max-width` property on the image and that image appears in some `div`. Real image's size is much bigger. Is it possible to get a real image's width?

Comment: How are you getting `image`? Is it a JS image object or is it a DOM element?

Comment: Could you throw a quick code example together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the real dimensions of an image by creating a new image with the same source and get the dimensions of that

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    var w = this.width,
        h = this.height;
}

img.src = $('img')[0].src; // or whatever
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVvk5/)

Comment: is there a reason not to use [`HTMLImageElement.naturalHeight` and `HTMLImageElement.naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)?

Comment: @siikamiika - no, those are fine as well, I suspect I didn't use those five years ago, when this was written, because `width` and `height` has better support ?

Comment: @adeneo I see, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=img-naturalwidth-naturalheight) IE6 through 8 didn't support it

Answer (score 1):

First, know that images load asynchronously, meaning you'll have to write your code so you get the results in a callback function.  Then, use a new image object with no explicit styling (so it can resize to fit native image dimensions) to trigger the callback.  For example:

```
function whatWidth(url, onSize) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  img.onload = function() {
    onSize(img.width, img.height);
  }
}

// Now get the dimensions of an image ...
whatWidth('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/keriyo-emoticons/256/Smiley-rofl-icon.png',
  function(w, h) {
    console.log('width x height: ', w, h);
  }
);

// => Outputs "width x height: 256 256"
```

It's worth noting that, while this may appear to require a request to the server to fetch the image (independent from whatever image object you're actually showing on your web page),  as long as the url is the same as the image on your page the browser cache will [typically] insure only one request is made.

Answer (score 0):

[Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) example with caching in case you need it (I know original question mentioned JS, but the logic stays the same):

```
class _IconSize {
  final int width;
  final int height;

  _IconSize(this.width, this.height);
}


class IconLoader {
  static final IconLoader _this = new IconLoader._init();
  factory IconLoader() => _this;

  // Url -> dimensions.
  final Map<String, _IconSize> _cache = {};

  IconLoader._init() {}

  void withSize(String url, void onLoaded(int width, int height)) {
    if (_cache.containsKey(url)) {
      onLoaded(_cache[url].width, _cache[url].height);

    } else {
      final ImageElement img = new ImageElement();
      img.onLoad.listen((_) {
        var iconSize = new _IconSize(img.width, img.height);
        _cache[url] = iconSize;
        withSize(url, onLoaded);
      });
      img.src = url;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a `naturalWidth` property. [Thanks w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalwidth.asp)!

Answer (score -1):

You need to access it on the image's onload event

**JS**

```
  var testImg = document.getElementById('testImg'), 
    iWidth=document.getElementById('width'),
    iHeight =    document.getElementById('height');

    testImg.onload = function(){
        console.log(this);
        iWidth.value=this.width;
        iHeight.value=this.height;
    };
```

Here is the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/mac1175/evgP8/

Comment: Because this is running into the same problem the OP is running into.  It is getting the DOM element's width, not the original image's width.  Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/65JJE/